# I need to hold ctrl key, when grabbing object

Tags: transforms

Anytime I want to grab and move anything, I have to have the CTRL key pressed down. If I don't hold it continuously, the position of grabbed item will reset. It doesn't happen when I'm rotating or scaling, then the CTRL key serves as an increment button.

Answer (score 2):

You may have Snapping To Increment toggled on. Click the magnet icon or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]